# How to convert a String containing Scientific Notation to correct Javascript number format?

Tags: javascript

I want to parse and convert an exponential value into a number 4.556456456465546e+25 should give 45564564564655456456456456 What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: Seriously ? A question with the **exact** same title already exists

Comment: Scientific notation *is* a correct JavaScript number format already.

Comment: Number(" 4.556456456465546E25")